# Can't deploy firebase functions - Incorrect data check

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Once it worked fine, I don't know what I did, but it stopped to work

Now. every time I'm getting this error:

Error: FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch `https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/services/artifactregistry.googleapis.com: incorrect data check`

Tried to re-install firebase tools, re-init the project and clear cache. I expect to be able to deploy functions.

Comment: try enabling [artifact-registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/enable-service)

Comment: Can you also share log from `firebase-debug.log` or deploying again with `--debug` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to corrupted ZIP files in the current versions I was using.

Solved it by installing:
`npm i firebase-tools@11.30.0`